# How can I search only files that start with a certain character using ag?

Tags: ag

Let's say I have two files in a directory:

```
.test
test.txt
```

How can I limit my `ag` search to only files that begin with a `.`?

I have tried a number of patterns, but none worked.

Comment: Well I stumbled upon a way to do this using zsh's expansion, but it only works by listing the files in the current directory (`ag foo .*` where `.*` resolves to `.test`). This was ok for my current need, but not satisfactory as a robust solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I limit my ag search to only files that begin with a .?

Like this:

```
ag -u -G ^\..*$ PATTERN
```

In your example, the file `.test` is hidden, so the option `-u` comes in handy. This option is probably what you missed in your search.

Let me explain the regular expression `^\..*$`:

- `^` means: *the beginning of the string*
- `\.` means: *a dot character*
- `.*` means: *any character* (`.`) *any number of times* (`*`)
- `$` is optional; it marks the end of the string to match

Note: I opened a [bug tracker](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher/issues/1074) for ag, because I see the search is not limited to files whose names start with `.` as it should be for this regular expression.

---

More generally, to search PATTERN in files whose names match REGEX, one can use:

```
ag -G REGEX PATTERN
```

(same as `ag --file-search-regex REGEX PATTERN`)

Check the manual for more information on ag.

Comment: Ah, so this is currently a bug with ag! I was trying many variations of that pattern without luck. Care to link to the issue so I can follow?

Comment: I updated the bug tracker to provide debug info (using ag option `-D`).